# Unable to render something with pvpython (paraview)

Tags: paraview, pvpython

I'm new on paraview, and I want to make a script that render a vtk file, using only pvpython. Therefore, I wrote this script

```
from paraview.simple import *
from paraview.vtk.vtkFiltersSources import vtkSphereSource
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
renderView1.ViewSize = [1080, 860]
reader = OpenDataFile([nameFile...])
Interact()
Render()
```

But when I launch the script with pvpython using the command `.\pvpython.exe .\myscript.py`, the visualisation shows an empty window, without my mesh [image: Visualisation without my mest]

Does someone have an idea, of why my mesh isn't rendered in the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add your reader output in the view, you have to call `Show()` before `Interact()`.

`Show()` will add the current active object in the view. To explicitly add your reader output in the view, you may use `Show(reader)`

Calling `Render()` is also unneeded just after `Interact()`

*edit* Here is a minimal script to load a file and display it centered in a default 3d view:

```py
from paraview.simple import *
reader = OpenDataFile("/path/to/your/file")
Show()
Interact()
```